# Why do I now have to click through comment notifications to get rid of the red number?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, notifications, global-inbox

Until recently, the comment notification widget (the white number in the red circle atop the "inbox" icon) could be cleared by clicking on the widget and then clicking away. Now, however, I have to click on each individual comment, which navigates me to the question. There are rare occasions when that's what I want to do, but definitely rare. Usually, I know about the comments because the question is the page I'm looking at already. It's really annoying.

I'm sure the change was made for some good reason, but is there a way I can control that? Seeing the fragment of the comment in the dropdown from the comment box widget is generally all I need, and red alert things like the "number of comments" thing really make me anxious, and it diverts me from doing what I would prefer to be doing.

*edit* — also it's even more annoying that if there are 3 comments on the same question, I have to click through each of them in the dropdown to get that red number to go away, even though they all take me to the exact same place.

Comment: No you click the "mark all read" link, you don't have to click on each individual one. Just like all other annoyances, this too eventually we will get used to.